# 'error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token' en llamada explícita a destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

¿ Como llamo de forma explícita al destructor de un miembro de una `union` anónima ?

```
#include <string>

class MyClass {
public:
  enum {
    Other,
    String
  };

  int type;

  union {
    int i;
    float f;
    ::std::string str;
  };

  MyClass( ) noexcept : type{ Other } { }
  ~MyClass( ) {
    if( type == String )
      str.~string( ); // <- AQUÍ DA EL ERROR
  }
};
```

Al intentar compilarlo con `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra`, muestra el error indicado.

Por probar, también he intentado

```
this->str.~string( );
```

con los mismos resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una std::string es un typedef para `std::basic_string<char>`, de modo que sería:

```
str.~basic_string();
```

Pero, ¿estás seguro que quieres hacer eso?

Comment: ¡ Que simple ! O_o. Tengo que hacerlo para poder *reutilizar* la instancia de la clase, y no ir dejando trozos de memoria perdidos por ahí.

Comment: mhhh... para reutilizar la instancia de la clase puedes usar el assignment operator o el move assignment operator, o modificar su estado con algún setter, pero ... un destructor debe desalojar de memoria los miembros que uno mismo creó con new, ... La string puede incluso haberse creado en la stack, así que no, no es para nada una buena idea.

Comment: Es para una *prueba de concepto* de un recolector de basura. Una cosa que salió ayer en el chat. En el código no lo muestro, pero la clase real puede contener varios tipos de valores, entre ellos `string` y `map`. Y se puede *reutilizar* varias veces, conteniendo valores distintos. Tengo que asegurarme que, si antes era un `string` y ahora lo uso para un `int`, la `string` libere adecuadamente la memoria que tenga asignada. No se me ocurre otra forma, mas que llamar explicitamente al destructor. **No** hago `delete`. Solo el destructor.

Comment: Doble contra sencillo que rompes todo :)

Comment: Jejeje ... acepto !! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Pureba así:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    using string = std::string; // Alias del tipo de la plantilla.

...
...
...

    union {
        int i;
        float f;
        string str; // Uso del alias.
    };

...
...
...

    ~MyClass( ) {
        if( type == String )
        str.~string( ); // Ahora esta linea es valida.
    }
};
```